# Create an array of objects with useState and spread syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state, spread-syntax

I am trying to create a very easy array of number using a loop and the spread syntax,
the goal :

```
    const number = props.numberProp


    const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([
        {numberName: 1, key: 1},
        {numberName: 2, key: 2},
        {numberName: 3, key: 3},
        {numberName: 4, key: 4},
    ])
```

but it dosen't work, my loop seems to work properly but it dosent assign the value to the array.

```
const number = props.numberProp

const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([])

let i = 0;
while(i < number){
    setNumbers(...numbers, {numberName: i, key: i})
    i++      
}
```

I looked for tutorials and videos but didn't manage to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set a new value make sure you add previous also

```
const number = props.numberProp;

const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);

const nums = [];
for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  nums.push({ numberName: i, key: i });
}
setNumbers((numbers) => [...numbers, ...nums]);
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answear but it's still not working, I have an infinite loop and it's assigning `number` instead of `i`, I looked if `i` was the problem but no, it dosen't work even if I assign a specific value to `i`. here is what `console.log(numbers)' looks like : 0: ' {numberName: 33, key: 33}
1: {numberName: 33, key: 33}
2: {numberName: 33, key: 33}
3: {numberName: 33, key: 33}' and so on...

Comment: @owdji I've updated my answer hope that helps and it's more performant also.

Comment: With your code I managed to do the array after that my component was still rerendering an infinite time but this problem was solved with useEffect(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here :

- you're forgotting `[` in your `setNumbers`
- setting a state is asynchronous, so you must use the previous value provided by `setNumbers` :

```
setNumbers(prev=> [...prev, {numberName: i, key : i}])
```